# Proof of the hinge loss being 1-Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, machine-learning

Page 7 of https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs229t/scribe_notes/10_10_final.pdf

I've tried finding a proof online, but haven't been able to find it. In the notes above which are provided as part of Stanford's Statistical Learning Theory, the hinge loss is defined as:
$$
l(z,h) = max(0,1-y_ih(x_i) )
$$
where $z = (x,y)$, and $h$ is some hypothesis.

Is it possible to provide a proof that this is $1$-Lipschitz? Furthermore, in general, is there a particular method to show this for functions that may not have a gradient defined at every point?

I hope someone can correct my (wrong) intuition: If a function $f(x)$ is $K$-Lipschitz, then the magnitude of its gradient is bounded by $K$. But in this case, why is the gradient of the hinge loss necessarily bounded? Can't we choose two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ which are arbitrarily close, but correspond to different labels such that $l(z_1,h) = 0$ but $l(z_2,h) = 1$?

Comment: What metric are you using on the space containing the $(z,h)$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but no metric was specified; should I just assume the Euclidean metric in this case?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by Euclidean metric for the function $h$. I don't have time to read through the pdf and figure it out. By Lipschitz you need to show that $|l(x_1,h_1) -l(z_2,h_2)| \le L d((z_1,h_1),(z_2,h_2))$, where $d$ is some metric.

Comment: Ah okay sure thank you I'll try to work from that angle :)